Combine multiple non-continuous .nc files with getting nan filler in Xarray
nc files, each has 3 coordinates/dimensions: time, lat and lon. Each .nc files contains the same 36 time steps, and one set of lat and lon.
The code works, however since I use the outer join, and I am dealing with non-continuous lat lon (see image below), the area with no-data is filled with Nan. Is there a way to construct a datacube that will not extrapolate the coordinate which will end up filled with Nans?

This is the code I use to combine my .nc files into a xarray dataset
# Define the path to your NetCDF files
file_path = "columbia_south/combined_data/*.nc"

# Open multiple files as a multi-file dataset
# Adjust combine parameters if needed
data = xr.open_mfdataset(file_path, combine='by_coords', join = 'outer' )

